# Greek letters in filename

Tags: ruby, encoding

My goal is to rename all Greek-named files to English ones (just by changing the Greek characters to their respective English ones). This is my code:

```
lettersmap = {"α"=>"a"}
puts lettersmap["α"]

Dir.foreach('.') do |file_name|
  file_name = file_name.split('')
  file_name.each do |letter|
    puts lettersmap[letter]
  end
end
end
```

At `puts lettersmap["α"]`, it prints `a`. If I have a file named `α.txt`, it doesn't. I tried `letter.encoding(Encoding::UTF_8)` and `letter.force_encoding(Encoding::UTF_8)`; neither worked. How can I index `lettersmap` using Greek letters?

Comment: Are you sure the file name is `"α".txt` (or `"\"α\".txt"`) and not `α.txt` (`"α.txt"`)?

Comment: @sawa sorry you are right, the file is named "α.txt" (without the quotes), fixed the question

Comment: Why not use `file_name.each_char` and avoid the `split` part? You may want to just use [`tr`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-tr) to remap all the letters in one shot anyway.

Comment: [String#tr](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-tr) would be good for this: `"αβ123.txt".tr("αβ", "ab")
 #=> "ab123.txt"`. Oh, I see @tadman mentioned this. I'll leave the comment for the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Dir` methods default to the filesystem encoding (`Encoding.find('filesystem')`). On Windows that's either the ANSI or the OEM character set ([an explanation from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/unicode/cs.htm)) and still neither UTF-8 nor UTF-16LE (used by modern Windows versions). The issue is the filesystem encoding in your case can't represent the `α` character. Ruby then silently replaces such characters with `?`. Try printing `file_name`!

The solution is explicitly specifying an encoding that is able to represent this character via the `encoding`  keyword argument. [UTF-8 is usually a good choice](http://utf8everywhere.org/).

Example:

```
Dir.foreach('.', encoding: Encoding::UTF_8) do |file_name|
  # ...
end
```

Comment: I was printing file_name btw and it was indeed printing `?` in the terminal. If I sent the output to a .txt, it was actually printing `α`. I guess that's because of the encoding my editor uses (sublime text)